# PHP Update variable on submit form

Tags: php, forms, variables

What am I doing wrong? I want to be able to choose a year in a dropdown menu and set a variable equal to that year. Or else if nothing is selected the variable should be current year.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->show_errors();

If($_POST['Submit'])
{
$aarstal=$_POST['aarstal'];
If (strlen($aarstal) ==0)
{
$aarstal=date("Y");
}
}
?>  
<form action="" method="post" id="form">
<table style="border:none;">
<tr>
<td style="border:none;"><?php echo $aarstal; ?></td>
</tr>
<SELECT NAME="aarstal">
<option value="<?=$aarstal?>"><?php echo $aarstal ?></option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>
<tr>
<td style="border:none;"><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="formsubmit" value="Opdater"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: There is no close tag for `<select>` and better add a semicolon to the `echo` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP code should be this, NOTE: you have typo's everywhere see for example your IF statement should start with lower case letters,

```
    <?php 
        if($_POST['Submit']) {
            $aarstal = $_POST['aarstal'];
            echo "found value = " . $aarstal;
            var_dump($aarstal);
        } else {
            $aarstal = date("Y");
            echo "default year";
            var_dump($aarstal);
        }
    ?>
```

also you had your html with typos etc correct one should be this

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form">
    <table style="border:none;">
        <tr>
            <td style="border:none;"></td>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $aarstal ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <select name="aarstal">
            <option value="<?php echo $aarstal ?>">
                <?php echo $aarstal ?>       
            </option>
            <!-- <option value="">2017</option> -->
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border:none;">
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="formsubmit" value="Opdater">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

As you logic was right but unfortunately full of typo mistakes, That was not actually the reason of your program not working. The main point you missed was to write value attribute in option tag like this

```
<option value="<?php echo $aarstal ?>">
```

same goes for other options value attribute as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I found out from the answers and I have tried to clean it up know. I'll try your example. Thanks

Comment: great! please let me know if i can help you further!

Answer (score 0):

```
If($_POST['Submit'])
{
    $aarstal=$_POST['aarstal'];

    If (strlen($aarstal) ==0)
    {
        $aarstal=date("Y");
    }

}
```

Comment: How is this any different from the code in the question?

Comment: Hey Nisse, *someone* changed the question to match my answer. There was no reference to "strlen" initially.

Comment: Right, I see that now. I've edited your answer to save it from deletion, in case it is still in the Low Quality review queue. In the future, it would be helpful if you could provide some kind of explanation in addition to the code.

Comment: You can delete the answer. It was simple solution to simple question.

Answer (score 0):

All your options have an empty value

```
<option value="">2017</option>
```

You need to change the value to the actual value or remove the attribute whatsoever which will cause the inner content of the value to be passed as the value:

```
<option value="2017">2017</option>
```

or

```
<option>2017</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$aarstal = '';//ignore this line if this value can be pass from another function
If(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $aarstal=$_POST['aarstal'];
    If ($aarstal == ''){
        $aarstal=date("Y");
    }
}
```